# KeyError when trying to export information from Grafana API

Tags: python, grafana

I have a grafana running in a container on a vm and I expose port 3000 on my localhost. I have a code in python that exports a dashboard information in CSV format, but when I specify the grafana API key I get the following error:

```
File "grafana-exporter.py", line 10, in <module>
    API_KEY = os.environ["my-api-key"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'my-api-key'
```

My code:

```py
import csv
import os
import requests

HOST = 'http://localhost:3000'
API_KEY = os.environ["grafana_api_key"]

DASHBOARD_URI = '<dashboard-uri>'
OUTPUT_CSV_FILE = 'dashboard_info.csv'

def export_dashboard_info():
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % (API_KEY,)}
    response = requests.get('%s/api/dashboards/%s' % (HOST, DASHBOARD_URI), headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    dashboard_data = response.json()['dashboard']

    # Prepare the CSV file
    with open(OUTPUT_CSV_FILE, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

        # Write the header row with the keys of the dashboard_data dictionary
        writer.writerow(dashboard_data.keys())

        # Write the data row with the values of the dashboard_data dictionary
        writer.writerow(dashboard_data.values())

    print("Dashboard information exported to", OUTPUT_CSV_FILE)

# Call the export function
export_dashboard_info()`
```

I am trying to export the API_KEY variable, and I expect to have an export of grafana dashboard in CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python script is trying to access an environment variable called "my-api-key", but it's not found.

If you're using bash, you can set the environment variable using the `export` command before running your Python script:

```
export my-api-key=your_api
```

Just replace `your_api` with your actual Grafana API key. After setting the environment variable, run your Python script in the same terminal:

```
python grafana-exporter.py
```

This should fix the `KeyError` you're seeing.

And your script is expecting the environment variable to be named `grafana_api_key`, not `my-api-key`. So you may want to set your environment variable as follows instead:

```
export grafana_api_key=your_api
```

And make sure your Python code is trying to access the correct environment variable:

```
API_KEY = os.environ["grafana_api_key"]
```

This should resolve the issue and your script should successfully export Grafana dashboard information to a CSV file.